# Restrict values for attribute with xsd

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a xsd file that looks like this:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="Configurations">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Schema">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Table">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Key">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Column" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                    <xs:attribute name="Value" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                        <xs:attribute name="Value" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
<xs:attribute name="ConnectionString" type="xs:string" use="required" />
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
```

And I just can't figure out how to create an `xs:enumeration` for the `Name` attribute of the `Schema` element, so that just a few specified values can be used for that attribute. I'm not any good at xsd, a little help would be appreciated:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to reuse the restricted type for all your `Name` attributes, add a `simpleType` at the root level:

```
<xs:simpleType name="Name_type">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Foo" />
        <xs:enumeration value="Bar" />
        <xs:enumeration value="Baz" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

then reference it as the type of your `Name` attributes:

```
<xs:attribute name="Name" type="Name_type" use="required" />
```